# Is Pinkwater in The Expanse a reference to the author of "Fat Men from Space"?

Tags: the-expanse-novels, reference

I mean in addition, of course, to being a [Blackwater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academi) reference. The Expanse series is highly referential (they even named a ship the [Mark Watney](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Martian_(Weir_novel)) and claim to be part of that timeline) and based on the age of Daniel Abraham, it's not at all unlikely he was influenced as a young person by Daniel Pinkwater's work. Just wondering if there is any reported info on this.

Comment: They even have an [Ayn Rand reference](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/153017/are-the-expanse-and-the-martian-set-in-the-same-universe/153018#comment396623_153018), I don't see why a noble don shouldn't reference another work in his book. Also, I've added both tags for The Expanse, feel free to delete whichever one you feel is not relevant (TV/books).

Comment: The Snarkout Boys and The Avocado Of Death by Pinkwater is a classic!

Answer (score 5):

Because they were doing private security, I assumed it was a mash-up of [Pinkerton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinkerton_(detective_agency)) and [Blackwater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackwater), but I suppose your explanation is also reasonable.

Comment: Nice take!  (I hadn't considered this angle, although Blackwater could definitely have been regarded as "Pinkerton on steroids":)