# Is there any "in universe" link between Matt Damon's character in Interstellar and The Martian?

Tags: interstellar, the-martian

I was just wondering because both movies star him as an astronaut trapped on an isolated planet. They also had fairly close release dates. I am wondering if there is a link between the two characters and if the movies were supposed to tie into each other.

Comment: Out of universe his characters tend to get in trouble: https://www.quora.com/How-much-money-has-been-spent-attempting-to-bring-Matt-Damon-back-from-distant-places

Comment: Care to explain down votes? If it's a grammar thing my question can be edited...

Comment: I don't see any downvotes.

Comment: My question had 2 ups, then 2 downs... but that's stackexchange i guess and badge hunters...

Comment: @Fabian as for now (21h22 here), there are 3 upvotes and two downvotes, hence the overall +1. You can see total votes when you get to 1,000 rep.

Comment: @Fabian. That's hilarious!!

Comment: The downvotes have most likely come from the belief that your question is "ridiculous". Users may think that given the two distinct names between the characters, the fact the stories are entirely different and the world and NASA in entirely different states, your question may be though of as silly.

Comment: @ProfetikOne - Here is the relevant help section on voting: "*Voting up a question or answer signals to the rest of the community that a post is interesting, well-researched, and useful, while voting down a post signals the opposite: that the post contains wrong information, is poorly researched, or fails to communicate information*". Note that while a downvote does not explicity say "uninteresting", many users vote that way, or as Edlo says, they think it's "silly."

Comment: This may interest you: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/153017/are-the-expanse-and-the-martian-set-in-the-same-universe

Comment: @Harabeck, I had actually seen that link in the related links section but yeah, it was a cool little nod from one director to another. I was thinking perhaps that the two movies I'd asked about had the same kind of thing going.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## No

Firstly, The Martian was originally a novel released chapter by chapter by author Andy Weir on his website and later edited and published as a novel. The novel inspired a film starring Matt Damon. The book was officially published in 2011, 3 years before Interstellar. Therefore the premise of your question is incorrect.

As for the possibility of them being the same person (besides the fact they have distinct names)

Mark Watney arrived on Mars in November 2035, however Cooper from interstellar, who Dr. Mann was of similar age to, was [born in 2031/2032](http://interstellarfilm.wikia.com/wiki/Timeline_of_Interstellar). The wormhole only having been detected in 2019, with the events taking place 48 years after it's discovery (Dr. Mann being shipped off 38 years after).

> For the curious: Ares 3 launched on July 7, 2035. They landed on Mars (Sol 1) on November 7, 2035. The story begins on Sol 6, which is November 12, 2035.
> <sub>[Andy Weir post - Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/462962073803090/photos/a.463868883712409.1073741828.462962073803090/682817308484231/?type=1)</sub>

> 2031/2032: Cooper is born in Denver, Colorado.
> <sub>[Timeline of Interstellar - Interstellar wiki](http://interstellarfilm.wikia.com/wiki/Timeline_of_Interstellar)</sub>

Therefore, Mark Watney would've been landing on Mars at around the same time Dr. Mann was born. The timelines don't seem to add up, Mark Watney would've been at least in his 50s/60s at the time he shipped off on the Lazarus missions.

> So Mr. Watney,” the boy said, “If you could go to Mars again, like, if there was another mission, and they wanted you to go, would you go?”
>
> Watney scowled at him. “You out of your fucking mind?”
> <sub>[The Martian - Original Ending](http://the-martian.wikia.com/wiki/Original_Ending) as recorded on The Martian wiki</sub>

Comment: Just don't let Matt Damon on any other space missions, for his own safety.

Answer (score -1):

Yes & No

No because it's 2 different movies based on 2 different books apparently and the characters could have randomly been played by 2 different actors

Yes because... we can use our imagination a bit here.

The Martian is like the heroes arch of Matt Damon's character, where he basically develops all the survival & agricultural skills he needs to survive a solo space mission. The space technology is advanced and one could argue that it's not too many years behind that of the timeline in interstellar.

Then in interstellar it's like his villains arch. It's well established before we even meet the character that his a well respected astronaut & scientist. And the fact that the Lazarus missions had the exact same parameters as the Martian could suggest that he was chosen to lead those missions because of the knowledge he gained staying on Mars alone...

So it's obviously a fan fiction theory... but it's pretty damn plausable

Comment: You seem to be arguing that there is a link between the characters in the sense that they have things in common from a thematic or subjective point of view. When answering questions on this site though, the focus should be on what is officially or canonically, what is intended to be true by the creators of the franchise/s in question. So unless there's evidence that one or more of the creators involved with these films intended these characters to be connected in some way, then the correct answer is that they're not connected.