# Has Ridley Scott ever been asked if the Alien franchise is canonically connected to Frank Herbert's Dune in a filmed interview?

Tags: alien-franchise

Since Ridley Scott was intimately involved in the Dune Film before, during and after the making of Alien. Has Ridley Scott ever been asked if the Alien franchise is canonically connected to Frank Herbert's Dune in a filmed interview?

Comment: Is there anything in one that leads you to believe it may be tied to the other?

Comment: ...or Ghostbusters? Or Harry Potter? Or Star Trek perhaps? Or the Law and Order-verse? Munch is everywheeerre..... ;)

Comment: The point of this question is not to debate whether there is a connection or not? It is to ask if Ridley was ever asked about it and what his response was. Thank you.

Comment: Why would you presume that Scott is able to comment on what is canonical in the *Dune* universe?  I think only really Brian Herbert has that power.

Comment: @NKCampbell - Plenty of authors have set their stories in someone else's universe; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/153017/are-the-expanse-and-the-martian-set-in-the-same-universe

Comment: @NKCampbell - The fact that alternate questions (on a theme) can be asked doesn't make this one inherently off-topic. We'll deal with those other questions separately.

Comment: well @Valorum - maybe not off-topic according to that logic, but certainly not a good one. If it gets re-opened on those grounds, I won't get into a vote to close war, but I'll keep the downvote :)

Comment: @NKCampbell - I'm probably biased in its favour by the fact that it's answerable and that the answer is moderately interesting (since Scott was intimately involved in the Dune film *before, during and after* the making of Alien)

Comment: *moderately* for sure. I suppose I can post a question if he's ever said anything in regard to Maximus being an ancestor of Ripley... ;) Director working on films doesn't mean they connect in any way imo so I'm just really struggling with the idea * behind *  why the ask is all. I'm nearly certain posting a question asking if Gladiator and Alien are connected would get tossed out as specious so I'm not sure why this necessarily isn't

Answer (score 3):

There appears to be no *in-universe* connection between Dune and the Alien universe although both (briefly) shared a film director in the late 1970s and H.R. Giger worked on both projects as a concept artist.

Ridley Scott was asked to direct Dune and was actively involved in the project during the late 1970s, including having multiple meetings with Frank Herbert but ultimately left the project after his brother died of cancer. He'd already passed on Blade Runner but picked it up after a rewrite.

> I was attracted to Dune because it was *beyond* what I had done on Alien, which was a hardcore horror film. Dune would be a step strongly, very very strongly, toward Star Wars.

---

You may also wish to note that the two universes are *technologically incompatible*. FTL transit in the Alien universe is accomplished by the use of hyperspace/subspace and is a mature technology that is essentially foolproof. By comparison, early faster-than-light transit in the Dune universe is described as being deeply unsafe, requiring the use of psychic "navigators" to remove the inherent risk of ploughing into objects. Travel in the Alien universe is very fast (thousands of times the speed of light), but travel in the Dune universe is near-instantaneous, resulting in the translation of ships from one point in space to another in milliseconds.

Comment: It should be noted that they only need psychic man-monsters in dune due to the banning of computers. There is a varient of FTL in the dune universe that is simpler and uses computers and was used to initially colonize the universe, but it is now effectively banned.

Comment: @JohnMeacham - Yes, but deeply unsafe. I recall from the books by Herbert's son that the failure rate was approx 10%

Comment: Elder Noobernaut pebble ship shown in the first scene of Prometheus is not FTL travel.